# In a parent window, how do I know which button is clicked in a child window?

Tags: javascript, node.js, button, click, parent-child

In JS ...

In a parent window, how do I know which (or if a) button is clicked in a child window?

I have a node function which builds the HTML page and creates the buttons as such:

```
    tosend += "</pre> <center>  <button id='abort' onclick='window.close() '>Cancel/Abort</button> " +
              "<button id='acceptid' type='button' " + "onclick='window.close();'>Accept & Close</button> </center> </body> </html>";
```

Node sends the HTML back to the parent client which creates the child and
waits for the user response like so:

```
ws.onmessage = function(e) {
    const w = window.open('about:blank');
    w.document.open();
    w.document.write(e.data);
    w.document.close();

    /* wait for user to confirm */
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
        tosend = "";

        if (w.document.getElementById("acceptid").clicked == true) {    /* placeholder, see note below */
            tosend = "acceptid button clicked";
        } else {
            tosend = "none";
        }

        if (w.closed) {
            clearInterval(timer);

            ...
            ...

        }
    }, 500);
}
```

Note - I realize that ".clicked" is not valid.  It's just there as a
placeholder.

Comment: Events don't propagate between windows. However, code in your child window could catch the event and then call a function in the parent window via `window.opener`.

Comment: @Pointy - Thanks. Almost immediately after posting the question I stumbled upon the answer.  I will edit my question to show the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working by changing:

```
tosend += "</pre> <center>  <button id='abort' onclick='window.close() '>Cancel/Abort</button> " +
  "<button id='acceptid' type='button' " + "onclick='window.close();'>Accept & Close</button> </center> </body> </html>";
```

to

```
tosend += "</pre> <center>  <button id='abort' onclick='window.close();'>Cancel/Abort</button> " +
  "<button id='acceptid' type='button' " +
  "onclick='window.opener.setValue(true);window.close();'>Accept & Close</button> </center> </body> </html>";
```

In the client parent I added:

```
var usedconfirm;

function setValue(val1) {
  usedconfirm = 1;
}
```

Just before the timer in the parent client added:

```
usedconfirm = 0;
```

And replaced:

```
if (w.document.getElementById("acceptid").clicked == true) {
```

with:

```
if (usedconfirm) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You won't really need an interval for that. You could just attach a click event handler to the document and that should do it.

```js
function onUserSelection(event) {
  let tosend = '';

  if (event.target.id === 'acceptid') {
    tosend = 'acceptid button clicked';
  } else if (event.target.id === 'abort') {
    tosend = 'none';
  }

  console.log(tosend);
}

ws.onmessage = function (e) {
  const w = window.open('about:blank');
  w.document.open();
  w.document.addEventListener('click', onUserSelection, { once: true });
  w.document.write(e.data);
  w.document.close();
};
```